# How can I pass events from the modal body to the footer using lightning:overlayLibrary?

Tags: lightning-overlaylibrary

I'm trying to fire an event in the modal body, and have the footer take action on the event. I have tried creating both an APPLICATION and COMPONENT event. I have not had any success. Code below. Any ideas?

Controller.js (this is called in the component that opens the modal)

```
openModal : function(component, event, helper){
        var modalHeader, modalBody, modalFooter;
        $A.createComponents([
        ["c:UWB_modalHeader", {"label": 'Snooze Approval'}],
        ["c:UWB_utilityModal",{}],
        ["c:UWB_modalFooter",{"cancelLabel":'Cancel',"submitLabel":'Snooze'}]
    ],
                        function(components, status){
                            if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                                modalHeader=components[0];
                                modalBody=components[1];
                                modalFooter=components[2];
                                component.find('overlayLib').showCustomModal({
                                    header: modalHeader,
                                    body: modalBody,
                                    showCloseButton: false,
                                    footer: modalFooter,
                                    cssClass: ""
                                })
                            }
                        }
                       );
}
```

UWB_utilityModal.cmp (this is the body of the modal)

```
<aura:component>
     <aura:registerEvent name="UWB_modalClose" type="c:UWB_modalClose"/>
     <aura:registerEvent name="UWB_modalShowSpinner" type="c:UWB_modalShowSpinner"/>
     <aura:attribute name="modalName" type="string"/>

     <button onclick="{!c.showSpinner}">Show Spinner</button>

</aura:component>
```

UWB_utilitModalController.js (I am able to fire the event)

```
({
    showSpinner : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.getEvent("UWB_modalShowSpinner").fire();
        console.log('Fired Event');
    }
})
```

UWB_modalFooter.cmp

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="submitLabel" type="String" default="Submit"/>
    <aura:attribute name="cancelLabel" type="String" default="Cancel"/>
    <lightning:overlayLibrary aura:id="overlayLib"/>

    <aura:handler name="UWB_modalClose" event="c:UWB_modalClose" action="{!c.closeModal}"/>
    <aura:handler name="UWB_modalShowSpinner" event="c:UWB_modalShowSpinner" action="{!c.showSpinner}"/>

    <div role="status" class="slds-spinner slds-spinner_x-small modalSpinner slds-spinner_brand slds-hide" aura:id="spinner">
        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
        <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
        <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
    </div>
    <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" aura:id="btnCancel" onclick="{!c.closeModal}">{!v.cancelLabel}</button>
    <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" aura:id="btnSubmit" onclick="{!c.triggerAction}">{!v.submitLabel}</button>
</aura:component>
```

UWB_modalFootController.js

```
({
    closeModal : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.find("overlayLib").notifyClose();
    },

    showSpinner : function(component, event, helper){
        console.log('Caught Event');
        var spinner = component.find('spinner');
        $A.util.addClass(spinner, 'slds-show');
        $A.util.removeClass(spinner, 'slds-hide');
    }
})
```

What I want to happen: click the button in the UWB_utilityModal.cmp, and have the UWB_modalFooter pick up the event that is fired from the button click. Also, I need to have UWB_utilityModal.cmp respond to a button click in the UWB_modalFooter component. Please help!